# Calculations over UNION, merge query repetitive code

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this query a lot mainly because of the repetition which possibly could be reduced - hopefully.

The general idea is to display sums of each table for a given month and display it as a pivot table.

Current code is in my opinion very messy and repetitive but the main thing is it doesn't allow me to make the calculations, due the UNION joining.

For each month as following ( I assume this has to be a derivative table that takes values of the other and calculates this formula for each month ):

```
Calculation Formula = (
    employees_salaries + 
    employees_salaries_insurence_costs +
    employees_agreement +
    employees_agreement_insurence_cost + 
    employees_extras +
    employees_to_hand +
    employees_delegations ) - employees_deductions
```

Current query is working displays everything properly but the questions and desired output :

- Question : Is there any possible query minification
           - Possible query structure to enable the calculation formula

Desired output : Current layout is what needs to stay

I am trying since few days but I am unable to accomplish my desired result, any tips will be really helpful.

Output

```
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
|         employees_salaries         |       January       | Febr | March | April | May | June | July  |  August  | September | October | November | December |
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
| employees_salaries                 | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 | 15826.12 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
| Calculations                       | Calculation Formula |      |       |       |     |      |       |          |           |         |          |          |
| employees_salaries_insurence_costs | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |  5044.44 |         0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_agreement                | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |   250 |        0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |     3550 |
| employees_agreement_insurence_cost | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 | 71.05 |        0 |         0 |       0 |        0 |   178.65 |
| employees_extras                   | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |         0 |    1.00 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_deductions               | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |    45.60 |         0 |    1.00 |        0 |        0 |
| employees_to_hand                  | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |         0 |  111.00 |   555.00 |        0 |
| employees_delegations              | 0                   |    0 |     0 |     0 |   0 |    0 |     0 |        0 |      2520 |     540 |        0 |        0 |
+------------------------------------+---------------------+------+-------+-------+-----+------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------+
```

MCVE : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8RvfD3uA4cSSVgmhoP2co6/9

Comment: In my opinion the existing way is the best way

Comment: Perhaps, but the calculation part?